# I had my code yesterday and now its all disappeared

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been making a large pygame project and yesterday I had a proper fully functioning game and now I go onto the exact game today to find that all of the code is not there!

I am really stuck on how to get it back (I am using python 3.7)

Does anybody out there have any suggestions on how I can get my code back?[image: all code gone missing]

Comment: Backup your stuff, use version management (git etc) and ask questions on a professional forum for server/data recovery. This isn't programming related at all :)

Comment: Which IDE/Text editor did you use? Did you save them online/in the cloud? Which operating system do you use? Please provide more of this kind of specific information.

Comment: If your really desperate you could try to reset your windows to an earlier version with the file. But this is very specific, takes much effort, and probably isn't something you want.

Comment: @ChrisvandenHoorn I am using python IDLE 3.7 and I have not saved it online or anything I have just typically done it on my computer. I can try to pycharm and see if it will come back there

Comment: @EdChum thats not funny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be worth checking in the Recycle Bin...

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I have checked, besides I also have the file but all of the code inside the file has gone and when I go onto the file (where there is nothing) the area where you type the script begins to lag a little

Comment: Theres no need to worry now I have completed it from scratch so its fine